# import Foundation deprecated in Swift 2.2?

Tags: swift

I was trying today something in a Playground (Xcode 7.3) and noticed the following when I started typing `import Foundation`

[image: foundation deprecated?]
<sub>(source: [cristik-test.info](https://cristik-test.info/foundation_deprecated.jpg))</sub>
.

Is Apple trying to deprecate this kind of imports in Swift?